# Moving an XPages app from a Domino 8.5.3 to Domino 9.0 - keep Dojo 1.6.1?

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, lotus-domino

Have anyone done this?

I think this could be a major deal breaker if you need to modify all your JS code to work with later versions of Dojo to be able to upgrade your servers.

I have an application that doesn't work, out of the box, on Dojo 1.8x and need to use the same Dojo version as the old Domino 8.5.3 server does (1.6.1).

When I check the JS-catalog only dojo-1.5.2 is available (for some odd reason).
Setting xsp.client.script.dojo.version, in the application, = 1.5.2 will load this version but it seems to be missing everything from XPages - the catalog doesn't contain anything related to XPages, it's missing the ibm-folder.

What do I need to do to make an XPages application use Dojo 1.6.1 on a Domino 9 box, the same way a Domino 8.5.3 box does?

Thanks!

/J

Comment: Joacim, what fails? I've had Dojo code that I converted to use the new Dojo require statements in order for it to work with 1.8

Comment: I can convert it, that's not the issue. One of the problems is that it needs to work across domino versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to extract the DOJO 1.6.1 directory from the JAR and manually copying it into the correct directory (use the same naming conventions as the version(s) already installed).

Answer (score 2):

Dojo 1.6.1 was deployed on Domino 8.5 via a plugin. You should be ale to copy that across from a Domino 8.x installation or, if you've upgraded, it may still be there. It should be in \osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins. That's where the file needs adding to R9. It should be com.ibm.xsp.dojo_..., which is the format of the R9 version.

Comment: Did copy it, on the server, and quit/restart server. But I'm getting: No Dojo library found matching the configured Dojo library version xsp.client.script.dojo.version=1.6.1.
Do I need to do something more?

Comment: Make sure that 1.6.1 plugin is running on server - try tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.dojo command

Comment: Gives me state = installed for the bundle. I suppose that's a good thing(?)

Comment: That command will also pick up the R9 dojo plugin, so is probably just showing the R9 dojo plugin is installed. Check the full plugin ID. Also try tell http osgi diag com.ibm.xsp.dojo... command, but use the full R8.5 plugin ID. That will confirm if there are any plugin dependencies missing. XPages Portable Command Guide has the full list of commands and what they do.

Comment: No, it lists the R9 plugin as activated and the R8.5.3 as installed. It lists them with the full plugin ID when I issue: try tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.dojo

Answer (score 2):

As Paul Stephen Withers write You could try to copy Domino\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.dojo_8.5.3.20120628-0936.jar plugin to R9 and then set the property xsp.client.script.dojo.version to 1.6.1.

But I would advise You to try to run Your app in 1.8 dojo. This version is quite compatible with previous and there should not be much work in porting 1.6 code. Im speaking from experience here - we managed to port quite big app in matter of days.